# Por qué no entra en el if? solo entra en el else. Pero si elimino el else, sí que me entra en el if

Tags: python

"Aquí intento una función para sacar la fecha y la hora del final de unos .txt que le voy pasando, pero estos pueden tener estos datos en una parte u otra del .txt, dependiendo de si genera bien el registro, la fecha/hora están cuatro líneas por encima del texto 'RESULTADO GENERAL'  y si se genera mal el archivo se corta y la fecha y hora están una línea por encima del final.
En este caso si pongo solo el 'if' me saca las fechas del if correctamente, pero si le pongo el 'else' solo me saca los datos del else....en resumen como está escrito es como si solo hubiera archivos que no contienen  el texto 'RESULTADO GENERAL', pero si borro el código del 'else'y sus tres líneas de código me saca los que contienen el texto  'RESULTADO GENERAL'"

```
def extraer_fecha_fin (p_directorio, p_archivos_txt_mayusculas,p_total_lineas_test):
    file = open(p_directorio + p_archivos_txt_mayusculas)
    contenido = (file.read().splitlines())
    with open(p_directorio + p_archivos_txt_mayusculas,"r") as f:
        numero_linea = 0
        for linea in f:
            numero_linea += 1
            linea = linea.rstrip()
            separado = linea.split(":")
            busqueda_FECHA_fin = "RESULTADO GENERAL"

            if busqueda_FECHA_fin in separado:
                numero_linea_fecha_fin = numero_linea
                fecha_fin = (contenido[numero_linea_fecha_fin - 4][0:10])
                hora_fin = (contenido[numero_linea_fecha_fin - 4][11:19])
            else:
                numero_linea_fecha_fin = p_total_lineas_test
                fecha_fin = (contenido[numero_linea_fecha_fin - 1][0:10])
                hora_fin = (contenido[numero_linea_fecha_fin - 1][11:19])
    return fecha_fin,hora_fin
```

Comment: Puedes adjuntar una muestra del archivo de entrada?

Answer (score 0):

el problema estaba en que debo retornar dentro del if si encuentra la fecha buscada y también donde está ahora, tras el else.
Osea me faltaba un return.
Gracias,